# PDF Function in R: Escaping White Space in Path (Linux OS)

Tags: r, path, whitespace

This seems like something that should be trivial, but I can't seem to figure out why the following is not working. I have a directory structure in Linux that will include folders with white space in them. I am using `gsub()` to add the characters needed to escape the white space in Linux. I have a figure that I want to make in the resulting path using `pdf()`. The system call to make the directory works fine, but the call to the pdf function fails and I cannot figure out why, nor can I find anything enlightening in the documentation. Test code is below, followed by the error:

```
name <- "test string"
name_new <- gsub(" ", "\\\\ ", name)
print(sprintf("New name: %s", name_new))

# save plots
figdir <- sprintf("../figs/%s/hill/", name_new)
system(paste0("mkdir -p ", figdir))
pdf(paste0(figdir,"nls_mcmc.pdf"), width=6, height=4, useDingbats=FALSE)
```

Results in:

```
Error in pdf(paste0(figdir, "nls_mcmc.pdf"), width = 6, height = 4, useDingbats = FALSE) : 
  cannot open file '../figs/test\ string/hill/nls_mcmc.pdf'
```

Using `name_new <- gsub(" ", "", name)` to remove the white space works fine. So it is clearly something with the path and escaping the white space. The fact that four back slashes were required to get a path with a single back slash is kind of absurd, so perhaps there is an issue there? Any help would be appreciated. Using R version 3.6.3.

Comment: You may use backquotes\

Comment: @akrun backquotes?

Comment: Yes, try with that.  Also, file paths would be constructed better with `file.path`

Comment: I needed a figdir2 for the `pdf()` call that used the original name. The white space did not need to be escaped for that call, only the system call.